# WPF Cannot make the passwordbox element corners rounded

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am trying to to get my PasswordBox corners rounded to make it look more modern. I have successfully done so with my button and TexBlock. However attempting to do so with my PasswordBox does not yield the same results that I desire.

The xaml code for the PasswordBox looks like this

```
<PasswordBox
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="5"
        x:Name="paswordinput"
        Margin="170,0,0,0">
        <PasswordBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </PasswordBox.Resources>
</PasswordBox>
```

the same code worked for my TextBox and my Button. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: You can restyle it according microsoft documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/passwordbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PasswordBox` control clears the `Style` of the `Border` so you should set the local value of the `CornerRadius` property in the template:

```
<PasswordBox
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="5"
        x:Name="paswordinput"
        Margin="170,0,0,0">
    <PasswordBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </PasswordBox.Style>
</PasswordBox>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this blog post will help - https://www.kailashsblogs.com/2017/01/round-corner-passwordbox-in-wpf.html

Use the below code -

```
<PasswordBox Margin="10" Height="50" Width="200">
     <PasswordBox.Template>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="PasswordBox">
               <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" />
          </ControlTemplate>
     </PasswordBox.Template>
</PasswordBox>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also try to use the following code to set rounded corners for Password. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/passwordbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="paswordinput"  Width="100" Height="50">
       <PasswordBox.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="PasswordBox">
             <Setter Property="Template" >
                  <Setter.Value>
                       <ControlTemplate>
                           <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" />
                       </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
           </Style>
      </PasswordBox.Resources>
</PasswordBox>
```